# Python reset cumulative sum over intervals in a column

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to do cumulative sum by intervals ie. with cumsum being reset to zero if the next value to accumulate is 0.  Below is an example with the desired result following.  I have tried using numpy 'convolve' and 'groupby' but can't get come up with a way to do the reset except by creating a def that loops over all the rows.  Is there a clever approach I'm missing?  Note that the real data in column 'x' are real numbers separated by 0's.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],\
[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[1,0],[0,0]], columns=["x","y"])

def patch(k):
  k["z"] = k.x.cumsum()
  return k

print(patch(a))
```

Current output:

```
    x  y  z
0   0  0  0
1   1  0  1
2   1  0  2
3   1  0  3
4   0  0  3
6   0  0  3
7   0  0  3
9   0  0  3
10  0  0  3
12  0  0  3
13  1  0  4
15  1  0  5
16  0  0  5
```

Desired output:

```
    x  y  z
0   0  0  0
1   1  0  1
2   1  0  2
3   1  0  3
4   0  0  0
6   0  0  0
7   0  0  0
9   0  0  0
10  0  0  0
12  0  0  0
13  1  0  1
15  1  0  2
16  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do groupby on cumsum:

```
a['z'] = a.groupby(a['x'].eq(0).cumsum())['x'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    x  y  z
0   0  0  0
1   1  0  1
2   1  0  2
3   1  0  3
4   0  0  0
6   0  0  0
7   0  0  0
9   0  0  0
10  0  0  0
12  0  0  0
13  1  0  1
15  1  0  2
16  0  0  0
```

Comment: @uMdRupert what does `y` has anything to do with this?

Comment: Fastest answer ever.  Haven't figured out how it works yet, but thank you.

Comment: @QuangHoang I think op wants the cumsum to be reset if the next sum value is 0, as opposed to the next `x` value.  I.e. in if `y` is `1` in row `4`, the cumsum should be increased to `4`. Not entirely sure, but that was my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @uMdRupert you anticipated my next question.  I wanted to know how to do it for one column first.

Comment: @MikeB2019x if you want the other column replace `x` by `y` inside `groupby`, i.e. `a.groupby(a['y'].eq(0).cumsum())['x'].cumsum()`.